# Give an array a value and a list inside of it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wish to make a list inside of an item in an array but still keep a value for that item? Is there any way of doing that?

```
resources: {
        hyphens: 0{
            rate: 0
        },
        ores: 0,
        pitchforks: 0
```

I want `resources.hyphens` to give back a number since I have that referenced quite a bit in my other file as such. But I also wish to be able to recall a value from something such as `resources.hyphens.rate` that is seeded in `resources.hyphens`. Any way of doing that?

Comment: There's an error in your syntax, you can't have `0` before the opening curly brace

Comment: Push objects in array...objects are the collections of key-value pair data...you can have any type of data in objects..

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish what you're asking. If you want `hyphen` to return a number, it needs to be an object property. If you want it to have it's own properties (i.e. `hyphens.rate`) then you need to make it an object. You can't have both though. You could add another property such as `hyphen.number` that will return the `0`, but as it's written, it's a syntax error.

Comment: @Johnny just FYI there are no arrays in your code, only objects. `[1, 2, 3]` is an array, `{ "prop": "key" }` is an object (in javascript terms)

Comment: @Daniel_L I understand that but it's how I'm conveying what I'm trying to do. I want to make a list in hyphens but have just resources.hyphens have a variable attached to it when referenced. It's probably impossible but i figured I'd ask.

Comment: I would refactor your code instead of trying to paper over legacy issues with strange getters and setters and `toString` and `valueOf` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `toString` and `valueOf` methods as own properties to an object. These methods are used when ever JS needs to convert an object to a string or to a number. Usually you have seen them returning "[object Object]", but for example an instance of `Date` will return a date string when converted to a string.

Creating own conversion methods:

```
var resources = {
    hyphens: {
        rate: 5
    },
    ores: 0,
    pitchforks: 0
};

Object.defineProperties(resources.hyphens, {
    valueOf: {value: function () {return 10;}},
    toString: {value: function () {return 10;}}
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8oLjgok4/).

You can create these properties also within the object definition, but doing it this way will protect the properties, and make them also non-enumerable.

Notice, that logging `resources.hyphens` directly, will show you the object structure, in the code it will behave like a number in a case a conversion is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but seeing how much extra things you have to do, I think everybody might just be right in saying that i should just redo my code to make it more efficient.